# Launch PowerShell from Command Prompt with custom prompt

Tags: windows, function, powershell, command-prompt

I'm trying to open PowerShell with a customised prompt (for instance the UNIX shell prompt). I have tried:

```
powershell -noexit -command "& {function prompt {"$(pwd)$ "}}"
```

But it just starts powershell without the prompt I want. It does actually work in powershell itself. Could I get this to work or do I have to make a seperate file and do it through "-file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the UNIX prompt defaults too but this should do what I think you want it to do.

```
powershell -noexit -command "function prompt {'{0}$ ' -f $pwd}"
```

If you use single quotes in the prompt function the `$` doesn't get interpolated, and you don't have to worry about to many quotes.

> [SAVING THE PROMPT FUNCTION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847739.aspx)
>
> Like any function, the Prompt function exists only in the current 
>       session. To save the Prompt function for future sessions, add it to your
>       Windows PowerShell profiles. For more information about profiles, 
>       see [about_Profiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847857.aspx).

Here's how to create a new profile:

```
if (!(test-path $profile)) 
       {new-item -type file -path $profile -force}
notepad $profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting on the command-line is tricky.  Also, & runs a scriptblock in its own scope, so functions defined there don't "leak" out to the calling scope.  The dot operator (also called dot-sourcing) is what you're looking for.  This is what I got to work using backslashes to quote the strings.

```
powershell -noexit -command ". {function prompt {\"$(pwd)$ \"}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom prompt to your [profile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692764.aspx) and it will load/run every time you start PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell customisation is always a bit tricky. Try adding a script with a method called prompt() like this:

```
function prompt() {
$myPrompt = "Ready>";
write-host -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor green $myPrompt
' '
}
```

Then call this in a profile, such as the one for all users:

`%windir%\system32\Windows­PowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1`

Good luck!

Comment: I would not recommend putting it in the system profile, do it in your user profile.